# Cosmos DB giving 'Storage quota for 'Document' exceeded' for small documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm encountering a problem where, the Azure Cosmos DB is giving Status Code: 403 Storage quota for 'Document' exceeded message for documents which are less than, 2 MB in size. I know, there is a limit on the document size but, in this case I tried with 5 KB document and it gave the same message. I'm using documentdb for storing JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb

403 is also returned during a POST to create a resource **when the resource quota has been reached**. An example of this is when trying to add documents to a collection that has reached its provisioned storage.

I have encountered this when I have tried to push more data into a partition when its size has already reached 10 GB.

Comment: You are right, my collections were at 10 GB size. I thought, the collections will auto partition themselves. Will look into it. Thank you.